# How he came from the term: $L^2 - X^2 + 2Xdx = Y^2 + 2Y dy$ to $X dx = Y dy$? furthermore, how does the term $(X/Y)dx/dt = dy/dt = v'$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

[image: exercice from book solved problems in physics]

I tried to solve by differente methods but wast able to achive the results in the book

Could somebody exolain the authors logic?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: $L^2 = X^2 + Y^2 \rightarrow L^2 - X^2 = Y^2$, the Pythagoras theorem?

Comment: but how it became 0?

Comment: There is a $Y^2$ in the RHS and $L^2 - X^2$ in the LHS (which is equal to $Y^2$). It's very simple math

Answer (score 1):

The eq relating the values is
$$x^2 + y^2 = L^2$$

Implicitly differentiating with respect to time.

$$2x \frac{dx}{dt} + 2y \frac{dy}{dt} = 0$$

Rearranging,

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{x}{y} \frac{dx}{dt} $$

When the bottom moves to the left with a velocity v, it follows that $\frac{dx}{dt} = -v$

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = v \frac{x}{y}$$

I know by definition , that; $\frac{x}{y} = cot(\theta)$

[Adjacent/opposite]

So,

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = v cot(\theta)$$

The angle that we want to calculate the speed for is 30 degrees.

$$\frac{dy}{dt} = v cot(30)$$